# Execute PowerShell script from custom project template

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2012, nuget, project-template

I am currently creating a project template and I was wondering if it would be possible to execute a PowerShell script after the project has been created (similar to the **install.ps1** in NuGet packages).

Any chance to do this without implementing my own [IWizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233750.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK... I have tried many things, but finally I ended up with the custom IWizard.

```
public class InitScriptWizard : IWizard
{
    public void RunStarted(
        object automationObject,
        Dictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary,
        WizardRunKind runKind,
        object[] customParams)
    { }

    public void ProjectFinishedGenerating(Project project)
    {
        var script =
            project.ProjectItems.FindProjectItem(
                item => item.Name.Equals("init.ps1"));

        if (script == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var process =
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
                "powershell",
                string.Concat(
                    "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File \"",
                    script.FileNames[0],
                    "\""));

        //if (process != null)
        //{
        //    process.WaitForExit();
        //}

        //script.Delete();
    }

    public void ProjectItemFinishedGenerating(ProjectItem projectItem)
    { }

    public bool ShouldAddProjectItem(string filePath)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void BeforeOpeningFile(ProjectItem projectItem)
    { }

    public void RunFinished()
    { }
}
```

Comment: This works. And don't believe [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185301.aspx) that .dll with your wizard could only be deployed to GAC. Assembly can be unsigned and deployed with VSIX, check [this article](http://oncoding.blogspot.com/2012/04/visual-studio-template-wizards-without.html) (works great for me).

Comment: I had an issue with   var script = project.ProjectItems.FindProjectItem(              item => item.Name.Equals("init.ps1"));

The error was ProjectItems does not contain a definition for FindProjectItem and no extension method 'FindProjectItem' accepting a first argument of type "ProjectItems" etc.  ...(are you missing a user directive or an assembly reference)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It's just a simple extension method. You can see it here: https://gist.github.com/philipproplesch/88540038e0d446c93769

Comment: Super..found that...
odd right now getting project null thing exception for some reason in the ProjectFinishedGenerating line
public void ProjectFinishedGenerating(Project project)

Comment: Do you know how to keep powershell/cmd window open when using process.start?